# How to clip background image with SVG

Tags: svg, tailwind-css

I am using [HeroIcons](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/heroicons#react) with Tailwind CSS. You can change the color of the icons to a solid color by adding a `text-color` class to the svg. How do you make the color a gradient? I tried doing something like this:

```
<div id="gradient" className={`bg-gradient-to-tr from-black to-white`}>
    <XIcon
        className="w-7 h-7"
        style={{ fill: 'url(#gradient)' }}
    />
</div>
```

But the SVG doesn't clip the background.

Comment: a gradient url needs to point to the id of an SVG linearGradient element, not a div.

Comment: It also looks like the linearGradient has to be inside the svg tag and the HeroIcons react package doesn't let you modify that? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/linearGradient#example